# Get value of an input field after input by user with Event listener using embedded script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the value of a placeholder attribute tag based on a value entered by a user in a user input field.

I have tried embedding script tags in the html string I am serving/loading to the page in order to use an eventListener to target the id and store the new value in a variable that is declared outside of the  tags in my html string.

Here is the code I am experimenting with:

```
// Endpoint Resource
"<strong>Endpoint Resource</strong>" +

"<script>" +

        "document.getElementById(\"inputTokenRequestorID\").addEventListener(\"change\", function(event){" +
                "tokenRequestorID = event.target.value;" +
        "});" +

        "uri = \"/vtis/tokenRequestors/\" + tokenRequestorID;" +
"</script>" +

"<div class=\"form-group\">" +
        "<label for=\"eventID\">Resource</label>" +
                "<input class=\"form-control mx-sm-3 resource\" type=\"text\" placeholder=" + uri + " readonly>" +
        "<small id=\"InlineHelp\" class=\"text-muted\">" +
                //"GUID Type used for tracking." +
        "</small>" +
"</div>"
```

How do I capture the value of an input field after a user enters the data into the field, store it in a variable declared outside of the script tag, and then put its value as another input fields placeholder value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is this:

```
<script>
function change() {
    var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    document.getElementById('myInput').placeholder = input;
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="Enter something here.">



<p>
Replaced Placeholder:
</p>
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Watch me change">


<p>
<button onclick="change()">Change Placeholder</button>
</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gugui3z24/ceomk9xb/

Or if you want something more dynamic:

```
<input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="Enter something here.">



<p>
Replaced Placeholder:
</p>
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Watch me change">

<script>
    document.getElementById('userInput').addEventListener('input', function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    document.getElementById('myInput').placeholder = input;
  });
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gugui3z24/ceomk9xb/1/